# How do I convert .sh Shell Script to an AutoConf Configure.ac file?

Tags: shell, sh, configure, autoconf

I wanted to submit a PATCH to a GitHub repo but they use configure.ac to generate CONFIGURE files. I was able to write the patch in Shell Script but I don't know how to convert it to something that Configure.ac would accept. Please help

The shell script code snippet I want to get converted

```
distroname=`lsb_release -i | cut -f 2-`
ubuntudistro="Ubuntu"
poposdistro="Pop"
debiandistro="Debian"
elementaryosdistro="elementary"
kalilinuxdistro="Kali"
mxlinuxdistro="MX"
parrotosdistro="Parrot"
pclinuxosdistro="PCLinuxOS"
zorinosdistro="Zorin"

if [ $distroname -eq $ubuntudistro -o $distroname -eq $poposdistro -o $distroname -eq $debiandistro -o $distroname -eq $elementaryosdistro -o $distroname -eq $kalilinuxdistro -o $distroname -eq $mxlinuxdistro -o $distroname -eq $parrotosdistro -o $distroname -eq $pclinuxosdistro -o $distroname -eq $zorinosdistro ]
then
        sudo apt-get install libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can just add shell code to `configure.ac`, **HOWEVER**, **DO NOT** sudo install software system wide from a `configure` script.

`configure` scripts are run by non-sudo-capable users all the time and need to work for them, and even if the user running `configure` can `sudo`, the expectation for running the `configure` script is that it does not change *anything* outside of the build directory it is configuring -- and certainly not that it installs software system wide.

The `configure` script checks whether the necessary things are installed, and whether some optional things are installed. If something essential is missing, `configure` then should abort with a good error message in `AC_MSG_ERROR([...])`.

Such an error message might very well include a suggestion to install a package like `libpam0g-dev`, especially if commonly used distro package names differ from upstream's package name.